# frame size of view not changing in iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, ios11, xcode9-beta

My app has a button which rotates my view 90 degrees and changes its frame accordingly so it fills the screen in landscape.

The code is as following:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.tabsView.transform, M_PI_2);

self.tabsView.transform = transform;


CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake( self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

self.tabsView.frame = newFrame;
```

It works like a charm on **iOS 10 and lower**:
[image: Lanscape iOS 10]

But running it on **Xcode 9 beta 6 in the iOS 11 simulator** I get this result:
[image: Landscape iOS 11]

Is this a bug or did anything change in this version I don't know about? 
I use Auto Layout.

Comment: don't you think after transformation, view's height will become width and Width become height?

Comment: @Suryakant I thought that too at first but doing that just causes wrong results on iOS 10 and still no affect on iOS 11. 
The code itself is correct, it just seems like its not being executed on iOS 11 and I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution. It was necessary to add this line of code:

```
self.tabsView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

It translates the views autoresizing mask into Auto Layout constraints. 
With that I have the same result on both iOS versions.